# Thread level locale setting in java

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar, locale

I am trying to set timezone settings at thread level. For this previously I am using Date and Calendar objects and all of them return same Datetime. I have seen locale settings at JVM level but I have never used locale settings at Thread level i.e. If I create three different threads of the same class I would like each thread to follow a different Locale settings especially TimeZones.

So whenever I call

```
Date d = new Date();
```

or

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
```

I should be able to get different datetimes according to the locale settings.

Comment: Can't you just pass the locale as an argument to your thread constructor? And as @TheNewIdiot mentions, there is a factory method for `Calendar` allowing to specify a locale

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ThreadLocal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) objects for this purpose. Create a `ThreadLocal` object of type `Locale` like `ThreadLocal<Locale>` will have thread-local `Locale` object , which can be used to get an instance of the `Calendar` object using [Calendar#getInstance(Locale)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance%28java.util.Locale%29).